# Reversing a word in c

Tags: c, string

It is for sure simple but I am quite a newbie to C and I don't understand why the following code is bugging. The code is a simple reverting character position of a string :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   int i,length;
    char *word;
    scanf("%s",word);
    length = strlen(word);
    char res[length];

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        res[i]=word[length-1-i];
        printf("%d",res[i]);}
}
```

when I enter a string, I get a message : (lldb) in the console, and in the debugger : movb %al, (%rcx), EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

Comment: The phrase "the code is bugging" is not a built-in error message in C.

Comment: You mean "reversing a string", e.g. `abcdef` -> `fedcba`?

Comment: If you don't explain the problem, how do you expect people to provide an answer?

Comment: @MarcB, yes indeed, this is what I mean by reverting. So sorry not to be precise : when I enter a string, I get a message : (lldb) in the console, and in the debugger : movb   %al, (%rcx), EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *word;
scanf("%s",word);
```

Invalid write to non existent memory location.

Create an array like so: `char word[MAXSIZE]` or use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate memory dynamically. And use `fgets` not `scanf`

Some links to get you on your merry way:
 [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/),[calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/),[fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! I have still a problem, because the word doesn't seem to recognize white spaces (if I put 'a b', I only get 'b'). Btw, I have edited my post but how can I get my downvote off

Comment: word is just a variable. Your problem is scanf. That's why I said use fgets. And about getting the downvotes off I can't take it off for you. Only those who downvoted you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d",res[i]);
```

Use `%c` instead of `%d` if you'd like to output a character instead of the byte value.